# Rotate object particles in a fluid

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

Is it possible to randomly rotate object particles in a fluid (liquid)?

I'm trying to simulate the effect of a glittery snow globe via a fairly low density fluid. The problem I'm having is that all particles are staying in one orientation with no natural rotation.

[image: Wireframe screenshot showing particles inside a globe, all in the same orientation]

This tutorial is what I was using as a basis for my particle setup: https://youtu.be/ZNb8I4v53-A?t=52

I note though that the fluid particles in the example are so small, numerous and spherical that rotation doesn't appear to matter. As such, the tutorial doesn't mention it.

For my needs, I want each particle to slowly rotate in random directions. I have rotation enabled on my turbulence effector (only on for a few frames to kick things off). I also tried adding a very strong turbulence effector that only effected rotation, but that seemed to have no effect at all.

Starting to wonder if I'm using the wrong kind of particle physics or if I should just try it with object nodes instead.

Comment: Your last sentence is correct: you are using the wrong kind of particle physics. The one you use is simulating the fluid and uses particles for its behaviour - for simulating the fluid itself it is irrelevant what their rotation is, only the interaction between them to form the liquid is simulated. And if you think about it - you don't want to simulate fluid, but particles moving inside a fluid. The problem with the fluid simulation is, you can influence it's behaviour with effectors (which particles in fluid would be theoretically), but the effectors will not be influenced by the fluid.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that @GordonBrinkmann. I'll looking into the other particle simulation types, or maybe object nodes. Any suggestions about which route would be most suited?

Seems like I can't accept your comment as a solution, or even up-vote it. Much appreciated though!

Yes, sorry for not providing a .blend file. I'm used to Stack Overflow where people yell at you if you DO provide a file.